# Node js add dynamic property

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let fileName = "test.c";
let testCase = "Case1";
let test = {};
test.fileName = testCase;
console.log(test)
```

I need fileName property to be dynamic
What is need is, like below

```
{
 "test.c":"Case1"
}
```

Can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test.fileName = testCase;
```

Won't work in this case. Should be

```
test[fileName] = testCase;
```

Comment: Thanks works fine

Comment: @NijeshW You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ES6 [computed property syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
{
    [fileName]: "Case1"
}
```

This will be interpreted dynamically as:

```
{
    "test.c": "Case1"
}
```